# How to setup jqGrid Cell Editing Events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have an input box in a jqGrid grid that displays utilizeds the JQuery Hint plugin to add some text to blank input boxes when a user edits a row of my grid. In the event that the user doesn't modify a text box that contains the hint text, I need to remove the hint (reverting the textbox to its empty state) before saving.

I assume the beforeSaveCell event is the way to go on this, as described in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get Cell Editing events to fire. The docs state:

> These events are related to cell editing and should be used in grid options.

I assume that means I should put this in the config like so:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
  url:'url.php',
  datatype: 'json',
  pager: '#pager',
  hidegrid: false,
  cellEdit: true,
  beforeSaveCell: beforeSaveFunction,
  ...
```

However, my function doesn't seem to fire when setup like above. Putting the function in the colModel didn't work either. For some reason, I couldn't find any examples... what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have some problems in the implementation of `beforeSaveFunction`. First of all try with

```
beforeSaveCell: function(rowid,celname,value,iRow,iCol) {
    alert('New cell value: "'+value+'"');
}
```

The function will be called of cause only if the cell value will be modified. By the way, if the function returns a string value which is not equal to empty string "", the returned valued will be used as the new modified cell value.